# Any way to cap download speeds from localhost?

Tags: web-applications, web, download, xampp, localhost

For development purposes, it would be extremely useful to cap download speeds from localhost. For modern web apps it is important to load stuff dynamically (and have things like loaders, progress bars etc. while stuff is downloading), when it comes to implementing this functionality I have to upload the site away from localhost and debug there. Obviously, this is annoying and an inefficient workflow. I was wondering if there are any ways to imitate real life download speeds on a local server, as opposed to having everything load instantly.

I am using XAMPP on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good program, [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/throttling/). Just set up Chrome or whatever browser you're using to use Charles's proxy and enable throttling.